# What should be the block value when I first create a database in TDengine

Tags: tdengine

I know that block is determined by the system configuration parameter cache; The number of memory blocks in each vnode is determined by the configuration parameter blocks. But I still don't know the relationship between the size of the block and my data size?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the default setting, which doesn't matter.